# How can I hide a search button and show a spinner while my AJAX partial loads in rails 3.1?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, partial-views, ujs

I have a partial which returns results from the Amazon-ecs API (searches for books). It takes about 2.5 seconds to return values, so I want to add a spinner (and ideally hide the search button) but I've had a tough time getting it to work.

I already have javascript refreshing the partial with the results. I'd just like the button to give me a spinner (and hide the search button) until the partial finishes reloading.

Here is my main view (index.html.erb) which renders a partial of search results, each of which is added temporarily as an object in AmazonItems:

```
<%= form_tag amazon_items_path, :method => :get, :remote => true do %>
  <p>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>

  <span id="spinner" style="display:none">
    <%= image_tag 'ajax-loader.gif' %>
  </span>

  <span id="search_button">
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
  </span>

  </p>
<% end %>

<h1>Searching Amazon</h1>

<div id="amazon_returned">
  <%= render 'amazon_returned' %>
</div>
```

My only JS code is in the update.js.erb file, which looks like:

```
$("#amazon_returned").html("<%=j render 'amazon_returned' %>");
```

I'm sure this is easy, but I can't get it work. Thanks!

EDIT: my partial "_amazon_returned.html.erb" looks like

```
<table>
<% for amazon_item in @amazon_items %>
  <td> amazon_item.title </td>
  ...ETC...
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show the partial.  Also 'what' is waiting? rails thread? background process, etc. Trying to understand q a bit better as it's a bit unclear (maybe why no other A's).

Comment: Clarified the question and added the partial code. The returned values from the Amazon Advertising API are what takes 2-3 seconds to return. Hence, I wanted to throw up a spinner to let users know the query had been submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook into the `before` event to do this:

```
$(function() {
  $("form").on("ajax:before", function() {
    $("#spinner, #search_button").toggle();
  });
});
```

Then, in your `update.js.erb`, add this again to toggle them back:

```
$("#spinner, #search_button").toggle();
```

Comment: I apologize for asking for clarification, as I'm totally new to rails, but where would I put the "before" code? Also, I noticed the location of my existing js refreshing the partial vastly impacts the output - do I keep it before the toggle in update.js.erb? Thanks!

Comment: The first code block could go right in your view in a `<script>` tag. As for the second one, it's up to you if you want the spinner to go away before or after the page content changes; however, regardless of size, these should both happen simultaneously anyway.

Comment: Thanks - this is great. I was hoping to show the spinner and hide the button on click of the Search button, then reverse once the partial has loaded. The above code disappears the button and shows the spinner after the partial has loaded. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Aha! I bound to a click with $(function() {
    $("#search_button").click(function() {
      $("#spinner, #search_button").toggle();
    });
  });

Answer (score 0):

Went with Dylan's answer, added the toggle to the update.js.erb and inserted the following into the view:

```
<script>
$(function() {
 $("#search_button").click(function() {
  $("#spinner, #search_button").toggle();
 });
});
</script>
```

Very cool! Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You shouldn't add it directly into the view. Put it in a separate file or a file that is included in the page. If in a separate file, you can add `<%= yield :scripts %>` at the bottom of your layout. Then, in your view, you can have a `<% content_for :scripts do %><% javascript_include_tag "your_file" %><% end %>`

Comment: Also, why not add a `$("form").on("ajax:complete"...` on the form to toggle the spinner? Because I'm not sure the code in update.js.erb will always be called, if the model is not saved properly or stuff like that.